# Factory Bot fails to create due to uniqueness validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

**Models**

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :tokens, :dependent => :destroy

  class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :token

  class Token < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
```

When I call the creation of profile it does:

1. Create a Profile with id=1, user_id=1, token_id=1
2. Create a Token with id=1, **user_id=2**

So I create another user with iD=2 but instead, it should be the same user_id=1
If I try to remove the sequence(:email) it returns a validation error for user email uniqueness.

**Test**

```
it 'test' do
  create(:profile)
end
```

**Factories.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    password {'blablabla'}
  end

  factory :token do
    association :user, factory: :user
    refresh_token {"XXXXX"}
  end

  factory :profile do
    association :user, factory: :user
    association :token, factory: :token
  end
end
```

Comment: I would just use `email { FFaker::Internet.safe_email }` (add the ffaker gem) which will give you better test data and let you spend your time doing something better then debugging a sequence which IMHO is riddled with these kind of issues.

Comment: ok I'll take into account. The problem is that I don't want to have two different user. It should refer to the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  factory :profile do
    user

    after(:create) do |profile, evaluator|
      create(:token, profile: profile)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, there's a much simpler way to define your associations:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    password {'blablabla'}
  end

  factory :token do
    user
    refresh_token {"XXXXX"}
    token_type {'bearer'}
  end

  factory :profile do
    user
    token
  end
end
```

Next, if you want to use an existing record within the association of another record in your tests, you have a couple of options.

Option 1 - create the token and let it generate the associated user for you:

```rb
token = create :token
user = token.user
```

Option 2 - you can pass in a record for the association when creating your token:

```rb
user = create :user
token = create :token, user: user
```